# How can I capture the signature of a specific USB device and emulate it in the future?

Tags: usb, hardware, emulation

I have software that requires a specific piece of hardware present to be functional. I have the hardware but don't always need it to be connected to use the software. I don't need to emulate the functions of the device, only the fact that it's plugged in.

Is there a way to read how the USB device represents itself and then emulate that signature in software?

I am on Mac OSX 10.7

Comment: That depend on how the software detect or recognize that device. What kind of device is it?

Comment: It's a DJ controller. The SW is limited without the HW plugged in. I own the HW but hate having to have it plugged in just to organize my music and prepare songs. So my goal was to somehow capture the signature of the device and "replay" it for the SW.

The software is Serato ITCH, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you, but every usb device has a unique Vendor and Product ID. You can easily use this to discover if a device is plugged in and is the one you are looking for. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679480/details-on-usb-no-luck-so-far/17679571#17679571) details this and much more, however the first section may be useful.

To summarize, you must look up the Vendor and Product ID. Then you enumerate the attached devices and very simply check if the IDs match. If so, then your device is plugged in!